# Swiperefresh layout not working in coordinate layout inside nested scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout, swiperefreshlayout

I want to hide the toolbar when scrolling down so I use coordinate layout and that layout I need to use `webview`.
when I use `swiperefreshlayout` inside `nestedscrollview` my `webview` doesn't show up.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` outside of `NestedScrollView`:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Also, please be aware of using `WebView` inside the `NestedScrollView`, they might not work properly without adding:

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

To the `WebView`. Also, set the `android:layout_height` of `WebView` to `wrap_content`, then it should work as expected.